# Round pandas timestamp series to seconds - then save to csv without ms/ns resolution

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv, datetime-format

I have a dataframe, **df** with index: **pd.DatetimeIndex**. The individual timestamps are changed from `2017-12-04 08:42:12.173645000` to `2017-12-04 08:42:12` using the excellent pandas rounding command:

```
df.index = df.index.round("S")
```

When stored to csv, this format is kept (which is exactly what I want). I also need a date-only column, and this is now easily created:

```
df = df.assign(DateTimeDay = df.index.round("D"))
```

When stored to csv-file using `df.to_csv()`, this does write out the entire timestamp (`2017-12-04 00:00:00`), *except when it is the ONLY column to be saved*. So, I add the following command before save:

```
df["DateTimeDay"] = df["DateTimeDay"].dt.date
```

...and the csv-file looks nice again (`2017-12-04`)

### **Problem description**

Now over to the question, I have two other columns with timestamps on the same format as above (but different - AND - with some very few NaNs). I want to also round these to seconds (keeping NaNs as NaNs of course), then make sure that when written to csv, they are not padded with zeros "below the second resolution". Whatever I try, I am simply not able to do this.

**Additional information:**

```
print(df.dtypes)
print(df.index.dtype)
```

...all results in `datetime64[ns]`. If I convert them to an index:

```
df["TimeCol2"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["TimeCol2"]).round("s")
df["TimeCol3"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["TimeCol3"]).round("s")
```

...it works, but the csv-file still pads them with unwanted and unnecessary zeros.

**Optimal solution**: No conversion of the columns (like above) or use of element-wise apply unless they are quick (100+ million rows). My dream command would be like this:

```
df["TimeCol2"] = df["TimeCol2"].round("s") # Raises TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Comment: IIUC you can specify the dateformat when writing to csv `df.to_csv(file_pat, date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` should work, can you try this

Comment: @EdChum Thank you, that works great! Only problem is that I still need rounding. This truncates "sub-second values", i.e. `2017-12-04 07:05:06.767` should end up as `2017-12-04 07:05:07` not `06`

Comment: You still need to `round` the values prior to writing to csv so `df['TimeCol2'] = df['TimeCol2].dt.round('s')` and then call `to_csv` with param `date_format=......` should work, it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the date format for `datetime` dtypes when calling `to_csv`:

```
In[170]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[pd.to_datetime('2017-12-04 07:05:06.767')]})
df

Out[170]: 
                     date
0 2017-12-04 07:05:06.767

In[171]:
df.to_csv(date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Out[171]: ',date\n0,2017-12-04 07:05:06\n'
```

If you want to round the values, you need to `round` prior to writing to csv:

```
In[173]:
df1 = df['date'].dt.round('s')
df1.to_csv(date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Out[173]: '0,2017-12-04 07:05:07\n'
```

Comment: I could swear I tried the `dt` before `.round("s")`, but this fixed it. Oddly, on my machine at least, it is quicker to do:
`df["TimeCol2"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["TimeCol2"]).round("s")`
**t = 0.1729460 sec** than
`df["TimeCol2"] = df["TimeCol2"].dt.round("s")`
**t = 0.2761543 sec**

Comment: don't know, but a `DatetimeIndex` is a much simpler structure than a `Series` so there may be less indirection involved